# Hijack "swipe to next page" in UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

i'd like to prevent scrolling on the 3rd page of my UIScrollview and "hijack the swipe" gesture to trigger sth. else. Afer this action I'd like to reactive scrolling.

This does not work.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
{
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.frame.size.width * 2  ) {
        // disable scrolling
        scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
    }
}


// hijack the next scrolling event
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

**This delegate is not called when scrollEnabled = NO**

Thanks for helping

---

**EDIT**  EventHandler ist not called ;-(

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Default background color
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    // Create scroll view
    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.scrollsToTop = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;


    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
    recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    [recognizer release];
    [scrollView delaysContentTouches];

    // Create subviews (pages)
    NSInteger numberOfViews = 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfViews; i++) {
        // x pos
        CGFloat yOrigin = i * self.view.frame.size.width;

        // Create subview and add to scrollView
        UIView *pageView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
        pageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5/i green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1];

        [scrollView addSubview:pageView];
        [pageView release];
    }

    // Set contentsize
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * numberOfViews, self.view.frame.size.height);


    // Add scrollView to view and release
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView];
    [scrollView release];

}


-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"swipe!!!!");
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you disable the scroll view:

```
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
```

it is unavoidable that the delegate method is not called, so you need an alternative way to handle the swipe while in hijack mode. One thing you could try is using an `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`: instead of simply disabling scrolling, you could associate a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to you view and handle the swipe from the handler method:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
recognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
```

and in `handleSwipeFrom` you would reenable scrolling:

```
-(void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    // do your hijack here
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Should i add the GestureRecognizer to the scollView or to one of "SubView". The handleSwipeFrom is not called in my demo.

Comment: I suggest either to the scrollView or to its superview... also, don't forget to set the direction of the swipe (see my edit in a few seconds)...

Comment: Okay, i had to set scrollView.scrollEnabled = FALSE; before i get listen to that gesture ;-)